Query to count how many times a location_id from table A (_app_locations) not exist in table b
I have a table called _app_locations with location_id as index.
In another table called _app_signatures there are these columns...
signature_date, location_id, signature_label_id
I am trying to write a query that will show how many times the location_id from _app_locations doesn't exist in _app_signatures Where _app_signatures.signature_date is between a startdate and enddate and where the _app_signatures.signature_label_id=1
Table: _app_locations



location_id
location




1
Location 1


2
Location 2


3
Location 3


4
Location 4



Table: _app_signatures



location_id
signature_date
signature_label_id




2
3/1/2024
0


2
3/1/2024
1


3
3/1/2024
1


4
3/1/2024
1


1
3/2/2024
1


2
3/2/2024
1


4
3/2/2024
0


2
3/3/2024
0


2
3/3/2024
1


3
3/3/2024
1


4
3/3/2024
1


1
3/4/2024
1


2
3/4/2024
1


4
3/4/2024
0



Count times that the location_id did not appear in _app_signatures in the date range: 3/1/2024 to 3/4/2024 and the signature_label_id = 1
Expected results:
Location 1: 2 times 
Location 2: 0 times
Location 3: 0 times
Location 4: 2 times

The SQL statement is being executed on a SQL Server 2019 database
I've tried the following but not getting any rows returned
declare @location_id int = 2
declare @sdate as date = '3/1/2024'
declare @enddate as date = '3/30/2024'

select a.location_id
from _app_locations a
where a.location_id not in (
    select distinct location_id
    from _app_signatures b
    where cast(signature_date as date) >= @sdate
    and cast(signature_date as date) <= @enddate
    and signature_label_id = 1
    and location_id = @location_id
)
and a.location_id = @location_id


Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Your desired results list multiple locations, but you are setting a single location in your example? And are you really storing your dates as strings?

And what format are you dates in? dd/MM/yyyy? or MM/dd/yyyy? You should really use an unambiguous format.

And your sample data should ideally include slightly more data than the query, ot illustrate that its not all of the data that should be included.

And I don't understand your desired results. Locations 3 has no zeros so should be 2? While location 4 has a 0 so should be zero? I dunno, but they don't seem consistent to me. My understanding is count the rows if the location doesn't have a row with 0 in it.

I think your expected result is wrong for location_id 3.
It seems like you want to count the number of days a location does not have a 1 in the signatures table.
declare @sdate date,
        @edate date

select  @sdate = '20240301',
        @edate = '20240304';

select l.location_id, 
       datediff(day, @sdate, @edate) + 1 - count(distinct s.signature_date)
from   _app_locations l
       left join 
       (
           select  s.location_id, s.signature_date
           from   _app_signatures s
           where  s.signature_label_id = 1
           and    s.signature_date    >= @sdate
           and    s.signature_date    >= @edate
       ) s on l.location_id = s.location_id
group by l.location_id


Yes, I missed the location 3. Your answer is what I needed.
